# Retrieve Data that do not exist in the primary table, exist in the secondary only

Tags: sql-server

Problem:
I would like to retrieve the value that do not exist in the list table b but it exist in table a.

I don't know how to do it.

Please remember that the data will change very often.

[image]

```
SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[email]
      ,[phone]
      ,[cellphone]
      ,[none]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[datatable]

SELECT [id]
      ,[name]
      ,[email]
      ,[phone]
      ,[cellphone]
      ,[none]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[datatable2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT [id]
  ,[name]
  ,[email]
  ,[phone]
  ,[cellphone]
  ,[none]
FROM [test].[dbo].[datatable1]
EXCEPT
SELECT [id]
  ,[name]
  ,[email]
  ,[phone]
  ,[cellphone]
  ,[none]
FROM [test].[dbo].[datatable]
```

This will give you all the rows that exists in `datatable1` but do not exist in `datatable`.

If you want it only for the keys then you should use

```
select t1.[id]
from   [test].[dbo].[datatable1] AS t1
where  not exists (select t2.[id]
                   from   [test].[dbo].[datatable] AS t2
                   where t2.[id] = t1.[id]);
```

Comment: Remember that `EXCEPT` returns `DISTINCT` values, while other syntaxes such as `NOT IN` and `NOT EXISTS` would not.